PDAL readers.las Error returning GDAL Failure (1) "components of the compound CRS do not belong to one of the allowed combinations of ..."
Encounter following errors while trying to read .las data from LidarBC (dwld data here if needed). I am using pdal=2.7.1 and have libgdal=3.8.5.
When i try to translate the linked file with
pdal translate myfile.laz out.las

It returns the following errors :
(pdal translate writers.las Error) GDAL failure (1) components of the compound CRS do not belong to one of the allowed combinations of http://docs.opengeospatial.org/as/18-005r5/18-005r5.html#34

PDAL: writers.las: Could not set m_gtiff from WKT

Could not find any information on what is happening here. Is the file simply corrupted or not well formated ?

PROJ doesn't like the CRS of that laz file.
$ pdal info --metadata bc_092p078_1_3_1_xyes_8_utm10_2021.laz|grep comp_spatialreference

"comp_spatialreference": "COMPD_CS[\"CGVD2013 height + NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N\",VERT_CS[\"CGVD2013 height\",VERT_DATUM[\"Canadian Geodetic Vertical Datum of 2013\",2005,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"1127\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Up\",UP],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6647\"]],PROJCS[\"NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83(CSRS)\",DATUM[\"NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6140\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4617\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-123],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3157\"]]]",

$ projinfo "COMPD_CS[\"CGVD2013 height + NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N\",<etc...>"

input string: parsing of 'COMPD_CS["CGVD2013 height + NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N",<etc...>' 
failed: components of the compound CRS do not belong to one of the allowed combinations of 
http://docs.opengeospatial.org/as/18-005r5/18-005r5.html#34

I don't know why. Possibly as the vertical and horizontal CRS are reversed.  But you can override the CRS and specify EPSG:6653 (NAD83(CSRS) / UTM zone 10N + CGVD2013 height) instead.
$ pdal translate bc_092p078_1_3_1_xyes_8_utm10_2021.laz output.las \
--readers.las.override_srs=EPSG:6653

You may also need to specify an output las version of 1.4 (the default is 1.2) to avoid the following error:
$ pdal info output.las 
PDAL: readers.las: Invalid VLR - exceeds specified file range.

$ pdal translate bc_092p078_1_3_1_xyes_8_utm10_2021.laz output.las \
--readers.las.override_srs=EPSG:6653 \
--writers.las.minor_version=4

$ pdal info output.las 
{
  "file_size": 2430426297,
  "filename": "output.las",
  "now": "2024-10-16T20:54:30+1100",
  "pdal_version": "2.3.0 (git-version: Release)",
  "reader": "readers.las",
  "stats":
  {
    "bbox":
    {
      "EPSG:4326":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": -120.574332,
          "maxy": 51.73801385,
          "maxz": 1439.06389,
          "minx": -120.6006605,
          "miny": 51.72449891,
          "minz": 1062.094293
        },
etc...


Thanks a lot. i am going to follow up this to the LidarBC staff then !

Did not got the error PDAL: readers.las: Invalid VLR - exceeds specified file range. if if i didn't used the --writers.las.minor_version=4

Your pdal is newer than mine. Maybe thats why.

Yes, I updated pdal and the Invalid VLR error disappeared.
